# $C^1$-extension of function on a normal doamin

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, functions

Let $f(x,t)$ be defined on the set $N:=\{(x,t): x\in(a,b), 0\leq t \leq g(x)\}$ where $g(x)\in C^1([a,b])$, $g>0$ and $f(\in C^1(\bar N))$. Is it possible to extend $f$ smoothly on the set $Q:=[a,b]\times \mathbb{R}$?

First idea was to extend it lineraly in the $t$ direction via $f_t(x,g(x))$ but then the $x$-derivatives of the extension weren't continuous anymore (or i miscalculated them :)) Any suggestions, or does one need hard theory on this topic?

btw, are these domain called "normal domains" In german the are called "schlichte Gebiete" but i found no appropriate translation for it (of course domain is also not so good since $N$ is not open:) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F(x,t)=(x,tg(x))$. This is a diffeomorphism of the strip $[a,b]\times \mathbb R$ onto itself.The composition $f\circ F$ is defined (and is smooth) on the rectangle $[a,b]\times [0,1]$. If you can extend it off this rectangle, then the composition of extension with $F^{-1}$ will solve the original problem.

So, focus on extending off the rectangle to the top half-strip (extension off the bottom is similar). In the special case   $f(x,1)\equiv 0$ a simple reflection works:  for $t>1$, define $  f(x,t)=-f(x,2-t)$. The general case is reduced to the above by 
subtracting the function $(x,t)\mapsto f(x,1)$ which is smooth on the strip.

The meaning of "normal domain" is entirely context-dependent. For the kind of domain you described, no single (English) word will convey the meaning unambiguously to everyone on the planet. A definition has to be supplied, and then it does not really matter what the name is.

Comment: I just read this again. Could you comment on the following: How is the diffeomorphism on the closed set $Z=[a,b]\times \mathbb{R}$ defined? Do you assume that you can extend $F$ on an open neighborhood of $Z$ or do we exploit simply that all points inside $Z$ are regular points? Regarding the extension: Since you only extend to $[a,b]\times[-1,2]$ i assume that repeating this procedure or using periodic extension will yield the extension on $Z$ right? Thanks in advance.